# Moving specific elements after others but not to top or bottom

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, sorting

Assume I have an array of

```
{ "w", "w", "z", "a", "c", "r", "f", "d", "e", "c", "g", "f", "m", "z" }
```

and I have a rule that all "c" should be moved before "f".
The goal to to keep as closest order to the original as possible while following the rule(s).
A real world example is a an app which knows that some plugin "A" should be higher than some plugin "B" in a load list.

So the expected result would be:

Moved c before first f:

```
{ "w", "w", "z", "a", "c", "r", "c"<<, "f", "d", "e", "g", "f", "m", "z" }
```

or

Moved f after last c:

```
{ "w", "w", "z", "a", "c", "r", "d", "e", "c", >>"f", "g", "f", "m", "z" }
```

Is it possible to use LINQ or anything ready for such purpose?

I tried `OrderBy(x => x == "c" ? 0 : x == "f" ? 1 : (int?)null)` but it moves elements to the end instead. I want to sort only specific elements with each other but keep their position relatively to other elements when possible.

**UPDATE**

The solution should work for any inputs:

```
    public static char GetLetter(Random rand)
    {
        string chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int num = rand.Next(0, chars.Length - 1);
        return chars[num];
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> Sort(IEnumerable<string> enumerable, string first, string second)
    {
        ???

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        string[] input = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => GetLetter(rand) + "").ToArray();
        var result = Sort(Sort(input, "c", "f"), "m", "e");
    }
```

Supporting multiple elements ("m", "c", "f") and multiple rules is desirable if it doesn't complicate things too much.

Comment: Is it possible to use a `List<string>` instead? This allows you to insert/remove at specified indexes which makes this easier. It can be done with arrays but is harder than a one line LINQ.

Comment: Is this occurring in memory or is the LINQ being turned into SQL?

Comment: @RobLang in memory

Comment: Are you constricted to using the same memory block used by the array or are you able to do a copy-to-new-array method? (depends on the size of your real objects)

Comment: @RobLang there is no specific performance restrictions, copying is ok

Comment: May you formalise the resulting output? There might be many possible arrangements satisfying the requirement when all "c" precede any "f".What element arrangement is preferred? Do you what to minimise the number of inversions in numbered element permutation? Do you have to solve a problem for only 2 element types or more?

Comment: @IvanGritsenko 1. just keeping as closest order to the original as possible while following the rule(s), 2. solving with multiple element types and rules would be desirable if it doesn't complicate things too much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method does what you want:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Sort(this IEnumerable<string> enumerable, string first, string second)
{
    return enumerable.TakeWhile(s => s != second)
        .Concat(enumerable.SkipWhile(s => s != second).OrderBy(a => a != first));
}
```

The idea is that first the part of the list is taken until the first `f` (in this case). Then the remaining part is appended to it, sorted by the `c` characters first.

A drawback is that the list is enumerated twice (partly). If this is performance-critical you should go for an alternative that enumerates only once.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution:

```
string[] ch = {"a", "c", "f", "d", "e", "c", "g", "f", "m"};
var res = ch.Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
            .OrderBy(x => x.item == "c" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(x.index))
            .Select(c => c.item).ToArray();
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Your solution suits for this specific input but how do you specify "f"? What if afterwise I want to sort "c" and "g"? You sort only against "c" here.

Comment: @Vlad It works based on your rule: *and I have a rule that all "c" should be moved before "f".* So it doesn't care about `f` or `g` or ..... It sorts the `c` characters at the first and always produces the first expected result that you showed in your question regardless of `f` or `g` or....

Comment: You stick to the specific input. The rule is *all "c" should be moved before "f"* and I need to be able to apply it to any array of elements, not just this *"a", "c", "f", "d", "e", "c", "g", "f", "m"*.

Comment: @Vlad Can you show another input so that we check it?

Comment: @Vlad If `{ "a", "c", "c", "f",  "f" , "d", "e", "g", "m" }` is a desired result also you can change the `OrderBy` like this: `OrderBy(x => x.item == "c" ? 0 : x.item == "f" ? 1 : Convert.ToInt32(x.index))` by using this way you also check for `f`.

Comment: This would move all "c" to the start, all "f" after "c" while keeping elements at 0 and 1 indexes. I don't want to move "c" to the start, I want to move it before "f". I edited the question.

Comment: @Vlad Look at your first expected output: `{ "a", "c", "c", "f", "d", "e", "g", "f", "m" } `  the second `c` have been moved to the first in your desired output!

Comment: With 1st expected output I did this: those "c" which are after the first "f" was moved just before that first "f". I didn't try to put it at 0 or 1 indexes but you've seen those indexes as inputs.

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing you, please see the examples in the updated question, now they cover all cases.

Answer (score -1):

If In understood your question correctly I think you need to have a array rules in which you will defined the rules like which character should come first. Here I am adding a test considering your seniors. You can modify the rules and use it.

```
    [Test]
    public void CustomOrderByTests()
    {
        char[] ch = { 'a', 'c', 'f', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'g', 'f', 'm' };
        char[] rules = { 'a', 'f', 'c' };

        var result = rules.Intersect(ch).Union(ch);

        char[] expected = { 'a', 'f', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'g', 'm' };
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(result, expected);
    }
```

If you want duplicate element at same position before use `Array.Sort()` overload it will short the result without removing the duplicates

```
Array.Sort(rules, ch);
```

now your `ch` array will have sorted array.

Comment: 1. The output contains another element count which is not expected. 2. This just moves all them to the start of the sequence. But there might be other elements at the start which positions should be kept. What If I have *'x', 'r', 'z', 'a', 'c', 'f', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'g', 'f', 'm'*? I edited the question.

Comment: 1. what element count? 2. if you have another element add it to the rules array on it's correct position.

Comment: There was 9 elements, your output is 7 elements.

Comment: Those are the duplicate element. In expected array we know the correct position of that duplicate array. You can process with that position, isn't it ?

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing you, please see the examples in the updated question, now they cover all cases.